# 'mFocusedApp'' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, adb

Whenever I run `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'`
I get error

> adb.exe: unknown command window
>   'mFocusedApp'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file

Comment: do `adb shell "dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp'"`